The Graph of $f$ when evaluated at $y$.
The traditional Cartesian coordinate system is labeled as $y$ for the vertical axis and $x$ for the horizontal axis.
Suppose we have a graph for $f(x)=cx$.
When one evaluates $f(y)=cy$, it maps a number from the horizontal axis to some number on the vertical axis, $CoDom(f)$.
Now, also suppose that $y=f(x)$.
Is it valid to state, $y=f(y)$ for that input value.
Would that cause some confusion as the variable $y$ is assigned to the output of $f(x)$?

This sort of confusion is what happens when you play silly games with variables. Don't EVER use the same variable name to mean two different things in the same context.  In this case, you chose to use $y$ to be the input value in the function, even though in graphing functions, one normally uses $x$ for this role and $y$ for the output. There is no problem with violating that custom itself. The problem comes in when you then also try to use $y$ in its normal role as the output variable. When you used $y$ as the input variable, you abrigated other roles for $y$. It cannot fill two roles.

Yes, completely agree. My mistake.

Recognizing when custom has led you into misusing variables will become easier with practice, but it will always be a common mistake to make. Even after 40 years, I still occasionally use $n$ as both the dimension of a space, and an index variable for a sequence or summation, for example. But it will become more obvious to recognize when you've done so, instead of being confused by the dual meanings.
